# SQL Recursive CTE using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have two tables, one is a Product Customer mapping and another is a Product sharing table. Using SQL recursive CTE, given a product, I am trying to find all the products that are linked as a chain, mapped across the customers. In addition, if a Product is shared with another Product, I need to include it in the chain too. Hopefully, my example make more sense than the description

```
Product Customer Table
Product    Customer
  Milk     Illinois
  Milk     Michigan
  Butter   Michigan
  Cream    Wisconsin
  Honey    Wisconsin
  Cheese   Minnesota

Product Sharing Table
Product    SharedProduct
 Butter     Cream
 Cream      Cheese
```

For the above data, let's say my input Product is Milk, then the result set should include all the products - Milk, Butter, Cream, Honey & Cheese. Here Butter-Cream & Cream-Cheese are linked through the Product Sharing table.

My current SQL looks like this but doesn't really work more than one level deep.

```
WITH Product_CTE AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT [Product] FROM ProductCustomer
  WHERE [Product] IN (SELECT DISTINCT p2.[Product]
  FROM ProductCustomer p1 INNER JOIN ProductCustomer p2
  ON p1.[Customer] = p2.[Customer] WHERE p1.[Product] = 'Milk')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [SharedProduct] FROM ProductSharing b
  INNER JOIN Product_CTE p ON p.[Product] = b.[Product]
)
Select [Product] from Product_CTE
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your example arrives at `Honey` from: Milk > Michigan > Butter > Cream (via sharing) > Wisconsin > Honey.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CTE has issues with multiple `UNION`s.  Although it may be possible, it wasn't working for me.

An alternative is to use a loop that stops when there are no more rows added to a working table:

```
declare @ProductCustomers as Table ( Product VarChar(16), Customer VarChar(16) )
insert into @ProductCustomers ( Product, Customer ) values
  ( 'Milk', 'Illinois' ),
  ( 'Milk', 'Michigan ' ),
  ( 'Butter', 'Michigan ' ),
  ( 'Cream', 'Wisconsin' ),
  ( 'Honey', 'Wisconsin' ),
  ( 'Cheese', 'Minnesota' )

declare @ProductSharing as Table ( Product VarChar(16), SharedProduct VarChar(16) )
insert into @ProductSharing ( Product, SharedProduct ) values
  ( 'Butter', 'Cream ' ),
  ( 'Cream', 'Cheese ' )

declare @TargetProduct as VarChar(16) = 'Milk'

declare @ProductChain as Table ( Product VarChar(16) )
insert into @ProductChain ( Product ) values ( @TargetProduct )
declare @NewRows as Int = 1

while @NewRows > 0
  begin
  set @NewRows = 0
  -- Add products shared by the same customer.
  insert into @ProductChain
    select PCR.Product
      from @ProductCustomers as PCL inner join
        @ProductCustomers as PCR on
          -- Shared customer.
          PCR.Customer = PCL.Customer and
          -- Different product.
          PCR.Product <> PCL.Product
      where not exists ( select 42 from @ProductChain where Product = PCR.Product )
  set @NewRows = @NewRows + @@RowCount
  -- Add products linked through the product sharing table.
  insert into @ProductChain
    select PS.SharedProduct
      from @ProductSharing as PS inner join
        @ProductChain as PC on PC.Product = PS.Product
      where not exists ( select 42 from @ProductChain where Product = PS.SharedProduct )
  set @NewRows = @NewRows + @@RowCount 
  end

select Product
  from @ProductChain
  order by Product
```

Assumed herein is that the `@ProductSharing` table is unidirectional.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Looks like I won't be able to do this in a single query. Since, I need to execute this query from JAVA, So I may need to make it a SP. Thanks again.